# Unable to delete managed dll after using it in an asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, unmanaged

I am using NHunspell in an ASP.net web application. NHunspell wraps either Hunspellx86.dll or Hunspellx64.dll, both of which are unmanaged dlls.

The problem is this: when I dispose of my NHunspell object (which calls `FreeLibrary` from `kernel32.dll`), it seems that IIS is still hanging on to it - as evidenced by both windbg and `tasklist /m`. This is problematic if, say, I try to replace that dll using an automated build process, or run an installer to update my web application: everything fails because that dll is in use.

I'm wondering if anyone can confirm my suspicions that it is, in fact, IIS that is caching it? Also, why can I delete managed dlls right out from under IIS (even when `tasklist` reports those dlls as used by IIS)?

Finally, I'm looking for suggestions on what to do about actually being able to delete this dll for automated builds/installs?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The overkill option I guess is `iisadmin /stop` and `iisadmin /start` around those parts of your build - assuming your build is running with enough permissions.

Comment: Also have you tried [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)? You can do a handle search for the DLL name and see exactly what process is still holding on to the DLL - the IIS core service or the application pool. This might not tell you anything new, though.

Comment: We are having this exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on IIS 6 or greater, you could just stop the specific application pool.  However, what is the exact build command that is not overwriting the file?  We use a TFS build automation step that copies our files out to a test server running IIS which has all the dlls in use and it is no problem.  What I can't confirm is how it does that, I suspect it is using XCOPY but I can't be sure.

Comment: Yeah, we use a TFS build automation step as well - it's that step that fails.